# Migrating Parse to AWS - Multiple iOS .p12 Certs

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, migration, amazon-sns

With Parse, it has the ability to support up to 6 certs.

Following these instructions: https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3NE69QDHI7LJK/Migrating-from-Parse-Push-to-Amazon-SNS

It appears that it only supports 1 cert, would I have to create a new mobile hub project to support the other iOS .p12 certs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tim,

You are correct, the Mobile Hub project was designed for a single Applicaton ID and therefore each project supports a single Apple Push Certificate and/or Google GCM credentials. Creating a project for each certificate/app id is one approach because it also adds the proper permissions for each app user to create push endpoints (SNS Platform Endpoints). Platform Endpoints are what SNS associates with the device token to publish directly to those devices.

The only issue with multiple projects is that each project creates a new Cognito Identity Pool and therefore your apps will not be sharing the same identity pool, if that matters to you. For example you have USER A that logs into Facebook on APP A and then downloads APP B and logs in via the same Facebook account. In this case, this user will have the SAME identity across both apps.

The **alternative option** is to keep the one Mobile Hub project and create an **SNS Platform Application for each Apple Push Certificate** if these certificates each have a unique App Identifier (App ID).

If you keep the one Mobile Hub project and create multiple SNS Platform Applications for each certificate, you'll need to make the following changes:

1. Change the Bundle Identifier of the App to match the Bundle Identifier of the certificate you uploaded to SNS for your application. (eg. "com.yourdomain.yourappname"). Actually, you need to do this for both options.
2. You'll need to update the IAM roles (created by the Mobile Hub project) by giving each of your apps access to those Platform Applications. For example, each Mobile Hub project sample app has an Authenticated and an UNAuthenticated IAM Role tied to the Cognito Identity Pool for that project. When you enabled Push Notifications and uploaded the .p12, permissions were added to those roles allowing the app users to send their device tokens to SNS and create an SNS Platform Endpoint. Since you can only add one certificate per project, you'll need to update those IAM Roles with permissions to the additional Platform Applications you created in SNS.

I hope you have success with either option.